# Query to count the number of different departments that a student is studying a subject from

Tags: oracle

The database schema are as follows:

> depts(deptcode(primary key), deptname)
>
> students(rollno (primary key), name , deptcode (references depts(deptcode)))
>
> faculty(
>   fac_code(primary key),
>   fac_name,
>   fac_dept (references depts(deptcode)))
>
> crs_offrd(
>   crs_code (primary key),
>   crs_name,
>   crs_fac_cd (references faculty(fac_code)))
>
> crs_regd(
>   crs_rollno (references students(rollno)),
>   crs_cd (references crs_offrd(crs_code)),
>   primary key(crs_rollno,crs_cd))

The query is Count the number of different departments that a student is studying a subject from.

I wrote a query like this:

```
 SELECT crs_rollno,
       Count(DISTINCT students.deptcode, fac_dept)
FROM   crs_regd,
       students,
       crs_offrd,
       faculty,
       depts
WHERE  students.rollno = crs_regd.crs_rollno
       AND faculty.fac_dept = depts.deptcode
       AND faculty.fac_code = crs_offrd.crs_fac_cd
       AND crs_offrd.crs_code = crs_regd.crs_cd
GROUP  BY crs_rollno;
```

My idea is to count distinct pair of (students parent dept, course parent dept(can be traceable from dept that faculty of that course is associated with))  grouped by rollno gives the details of each student. Hence it should work.

But I am getting the following error:

> select crs_rollno, count(distinct students.deptcode,fac_dept) from
>   crs_regd, students, crs_offrd, faculty, depts
>
> - ERROR at line 1: ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

What is the problem?

If I am right, as the error suggests `count` can't take more than one argument, then what is the round about way for this query?

Comment: COUNT expression cannot be composite. You must convert 2 fields into one value. Use, for example, `count(distinct CONCAT(students.deptcode,' ',fac_dept))`

Comment: @Akina I wouldn't bother using the `CONCAT()` function here, particularly as it only accepts two parameters! Instead, use the concatenation operator instead - it's easier and far more intuitive than the function, especially when you're trying to concatenate more than two items: `students.deptcode || ' ' || fac_dept`

Comment: @Boneist CONCAT was used for to purify what must be done. For me, for example, the `||` operator as concatenation one is not clear... there are choices when this operator means something else.

Comment: @Akina but your example would need to be `CONCAT(students.deptcode, CONCAT(' ', fac_dept))` which is much more verbose than `students.deptcode || ' ' || fac_dept` and far less easy to type and read. The `||` operator might mean different things in different code / database platforms, but in Oracle, it's standard. (I know that in some languages, the concatenation operator is `+`, which I've never gotten confused with the mathematical plus symbol, despite not knowing that particular language!) I maintain that `||` is clearer than the `CONCAT()` function.

Comment: @Boneist *but your example would need to be* In my example the space delimiter is safety one at all - I am not sure that real data needs in it (in my code I use `char(9)` or even `char(0)` instead in those cases when delimiter needed strongly). *I maintain that `||` is clearer than the `CONCAT()` function.* When I see `||` I think primarily that I see batch-processing "execute if error" operator :-)... anycase when somebody see CONCAT word he understands that he must to concat values, and no variants - maybe solving some synthactical problems.

Comment: @Akina clearly, you have your own opinion which you are entitled to re. `CONCAT()` vs `||`. However, my point was that your `CONCAT()` example will error since it has 3 parameters, but in Oracle, it only accepts 2 parameters. Hence the need for nested `CONCAT()`s.